# I can't get Boolean difference to work when cutting shell from topograph

Tags: blender-osm, boolean-modifier

i already suceeded once in cutting out the shape of the paths im modeling(i then merge the object and the topography together), but when i try again on a larger scale it doesnt seem to work.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dtHng3hn77OJEbyR2lmYOZGgFwGCmD5f/view?usp=sharing
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html):

> Only Manifold meshes are guaranteed to give proper results, other
> cases (especially “opened” meshes, Non-manifold but without any
> self-intersections) will usually work well, but might give odd
> glitches and artifacts in some cases.

In your case, `terrain_alteration_north.001` is non-manifold,  put it into edit mode and *Select*::*By trait*::*non manifold* and you'll see that all of its vertices are selected.  In other words you have an open mesh that does not *enclose* the terrain to be cut.

One approach would be to create a face on the top and bottom of `terrain_alteration_north.001`.  I saw one `terrain_alteration_north` that appeared to be a planar, manifold version, so I just extruded that (along Z-axis) and moved it down vertically to enclose `Terrain` and thusly got:

[image]

here is a stripped down version of your file: [image]